# Replace The Second Occurrence Of Word In String And Return Whole String

Tags: php

**$string = 'Hellow there. Hooman lives on earth. Hooman loves cats.';**

Now, I want to replace the **2nd Hooman word** with **Human** and result should be as follow:

**Hellow there. Hooman lives on earth. Human loves cats.**

Here's what I've done so far...:

```
<?php

$string = 'Hellow there. Hooman lives on earth. Hooman loves cats.';

echo preg_replace('/Hooman/', 'Human', $string, 2);

?>
```

But it returns: **Hellow there. Human lives on earth. Human loves cats.**

Comment: `Hoomans` or `Hooman` ?

Comment: I didn't get to try what I wrote, is it working or not ? You validated the anwser and then unvalidated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_replace

```
function str_replace_n($search, $replace, $subject, $occurrence)
{
    $search = preg_quote($search);
    return preg_replace("/^((?:(?:.*?$search){".--$occurrence."}.*?))$search/", "$1$replace", $subject);
}

echo str_replace_n('Hooman','Human',$string, 2);
```

Comment: How long is your string ?

Comment: If i write Hooman Hooman Hooman in multiple lines in $string, it doesn't work at all. But if I write Hooman Hooman Hooman in one line, it works nice.

Comment: I used $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string));
to remove the lines and now it's working. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes there is at least one Hooman in the string.

Find the Hoomans position and substring  it there and do the replace on the second part of the string.

```
$find = "Hooman";
$str = 'Hellow there. Hooman lives on earth. Hooman loves cats.';

$pos = strpos($str, $find);

echo substr($str, 0, $pos+strlen($find)) . str_replace($find, "Human", substr($str, $pos+strlen($find)));
```

Comment: But it's replacing all the Hoomans after 2nd occurance as well

Comment: **Hellow there. Hooman lives on earth. Hooman loves cats. Hooman Hooman Hooman** changes to **Hellow there. Hooman lives on earth. Human loves cats. Human Human Human**